# Plus sign not aligned in systeme

Tags: luatex, systeme

I want to create the following linear equation in latex using `systeme`:

```
  \systeme[xyz]{
    x + y +2z = a,
    2x + 2y + {( 4+b )} z = b,
    -x -2z  = ab,
    y + bz = a + b
  }
```

But the result appears as:

[image: equation]

The plus and negative signs are not aligned correctly. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The plus and minus signs are aligned exactly as I would expect them to be. How would you think they should be aligned?

Comment: Adjacent to the variables, to the left of them

Comment: Then, you probably don't want to use the `systeme` package, since it also aligns the plus and minus signs. Maybe try `aligend` instead (from the `amsmath` package).

Comment: Sorry, I meant `aligned` of course, but maybe you figured that out already =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you're after exactly, but to have full alignment flexibility, you can always use an `array` (`@{}` removes the default column spacing, `>{{}}` inserts `{}` into the relevant cell to ensure proper spacing of the math operators):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[\left\{
\begin{array}{ @{} r @{} >{{}} r @{} >{{}} r @{} >{{}} l @{} }
     x &  + y &          + 2z & = a     \\
    2x & + 2y & + ( 4 + b ) z & = b     \\
    -x &      &          - 2z & = ab    \\
       &    y &          + bz & = a + b \\
\end{array}
\right.\]

\end{document}
```

[image]